# How to pass intent if String value is valid?

Tags: android, string, android-intent, android-activity

Hi I am working with android. I am passing an intent from activity A to Activity B with a string value.I want get the requested Activity only if the passed String value is valid in Activity B. How can I do this ??

Comment: But with which you want to check that if it is valid or not??

Comment: can you explain more? what is that 'requested Activity'?

Comment: I am passing an App id with intent.So I need to check App id is valid or not . if valid pass intent

Comment: @prince Want to check if Appid is null or not??

Comment: @piyush : I want check it with the server database, so if it available in database I can pass activity

Comment: so what is the problem? check that, if is valid send to next activity

Comment: Say, you are going from A->B on a button click. Create a method that returns boolean and call it inside button's `onClick()`, if it returns true, start the activity using Intent with the String data with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Simple example:  may be help you :)

First Activity

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
EditText edt;

String AppId;// Declare value what you need!

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class).putExtra("AppId", AppId));
        }
    });

}
```

}

Second Activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("AppId")) {
        if (getIntent().getStringExtra("AppId").equalsIgnoreCase(
                "your value")) {
            // do stuff
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Will abort if value doesn't matches

Comment: Thank you Sir this is actually i wanted :)